# How to change alt text of image who has empty alt text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div inside whose chile tehre can be number of images
What i want's to do is if there is any img with alt="" i want's to change it to alt="category"
How can i do it with jquery.
Currently ia m able to get all the img elements and trying to check there value first [so that if there is a alt have value i will not touch it] but unsuccessful
My current code is

```
var label = $("#viewCategoriesForBlog").find('img').attr('alt');
for(var i=0;i<label.length;i++){
    alert( label[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This action will solve your initial problem:

```
 $('#viewCategoriesForBlog img[alt=""]').attr('alt', 'category');
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$("#viewCategoriesForBlog img[alt=''], #viewCategoriesForBlog img:not([alt])")
    .attr("alt", "Category");
```

Selectors explained:

- `#viewCategoriesForBlog img[alt=""]` returns img tags that have `alt=""`
- `#viewCategoriesForBlog img:not([alt])` returns img tags that do not have `alt` attribute

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/YvsU7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var label = $("#viewCategoriesForBlog").find('img').attr('alt'); 
// label will hold only the first alt value
```

It has to be like

```
var label = $("#viewCategoriesForBlog").find('img');
for(var i=0;i<label.length;i++){
    alert( $(label[i]).attr('alt'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the elements in the selector. You cannot loop over attributes of the elements in a selector. Try this:

```
$("#viewCategoriesForBlog img").each(function(i, el) {
    alert($(el).prop('alt'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  $("#viewCategoriesForBlog").find('img').each(function(){
        if(this.alt.trim() == ''){
            this.alt = 'category';
        }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle alerts all the empty alt tags:
http://jsfiddle.net/4ZnJN/1/

```
$("img").each(function(){
        var label = $(this).attr('alt');            
        if(label.length < 1){
            alert(label);
        }
});
```

Might want to shrink it down to your specific structure in stead of all img tags

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that's absolutely not accessible, but here I only needed to avoid WCAG validator to highlight images with no alternative text.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

if(images) {
    for (var i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var alt = images[i].getAttribute('alt');
        if(!alt){
            images[i].setAttribute('alt', 'no alt text');
        }
    }
}
```